# Loops are Hard [Python]

Tags: python

Not a programmer by vocation, please excuse if this is obvious. I cannot loop :/ ...

I have 3 lists:

```
gene_concepts[0] = ['+0|+77|CFTR', '+12|+77|CYP2C19']

genes = ['CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 
'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 
'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19']

haplotypes = ['CFTR F508del(CTT)', 'CFTR F508del(TCT)', 'CFTR G1244E', 
'CFTR G1349D', 'CFTR G178R', 'CFTR G551D', 'CFTR G551S', 'CFTR S1251N', 
'CFTR S1255P', 'CFTR S549N', 'CFTR S549R(A>C)', 'CFTR S549R(T>G)', 
'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 
*10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10']
```

Note that the haplotypes and genes match (i.e., the first term of the string in the haplotype list is "CFTR", and matches the first element of the list in genes list...so these are ordered)

I want to build a new list or just output a set of strings, such that the haplotypes that have the same gene (so the genes may match each other, or the substring of the first part of the haplotype string, whichever) are assigned a particular code, which is found in the gene_concepts list, and corresponds to the first term before the "|" delimiter in the list of strings.

Output desired is:

```
+21|+0|CFTR F508del(CTT)
+22|+0|CFTR F508del(TCT)
+23|+0|CFTR G1244E
+24|+0|CFTR G1349D
+25|+0|CFTR G178R
+26|+0|CFTR G551D
+27|+0|CFTR G551S
+28|+0|CFTR S1251N
+29|+0|CFTR S1255P
+30|+0|CFTR S549N
+31|+0|CFTR S549R(A>C)
+32|+0|CFTR S549R(T>G)
+33|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+34|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+35|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+36|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+37|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+38|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+39|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+40|+12|CYP2C19 *10
```

So the first part of the text above is "+21...+39 is the temp_code_2"...this is just an arbitrary id I've assigned it to keep track. The part between the delimiters is the code I'm trying to assign the matching genes.  The last part after the 2nd delimiter is the haplotype.

Here's my code so far...

```
def generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts[0], haplotypes):
    temp_code_2 = 20
    index = 0

    for batch_line in gene_concepts[0]:
        gene_parent_code = batch_line.split("|")[0]
        gene_parent_medcodes.append(gene_parent_code)

    index_gene = 0
    index_parent_code = 0
    for gene in genes:
        if (index_gene == 0):
            print("+" + str(temp_code_2) + "|"
                  + gene_parent_medcodes[index_parent_code] + "|"
                  + haplotypes[index_gene])
            index_gene += 1
        elif (genes[index_gene] == genes[index_gene-1]):             
            print("+" + str(temp_code_2) + "|"
                  + gene_parent_medcodes[index_parent_code] + "|"
                  + haplotypes[index_gene-1])
        else:
            index_parent_code += 1
            print("+" + str(temp_code_2) + "|"
                  + gene_parent_medcodes[index_parent_code] + "|"
                  + haplotypes[index_gene])
        index_gene += 1
        temp_code_2 += 1  

generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts[0], haplotypes)
```

My output is this:

```
+21|+0|CFTR F508del(CTT)
+22|+0|CFTR F508del(TCT)
+23|+0|CFTR G1244E
+24|+0|CFTR G1349D
+25|+0|CFTR G178R
+26|+0|CFTR G551D
+27|+0|CFTR G551S
+28|+0|CFTR S1251N
+29|+0|CFTR S1255P
+30|+0|CFTR S549N
+31|+0|CFTR S549R(A>C)
+32|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+33|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+34|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+35|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+36|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+37|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+38|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+39|+12|CYP2C19 *10
```

2 problems I see...I'm missing the last CFTR haplotype (+32|+0|CFTR S549R(T>G) should be there instead) and I'm getting a "list index out of range" error.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
----
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-16-1410b2513457> in <module>()
     55 
     56 
---> 57 generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts[0], haplotypes)

<ipython-input-16-1410b2513457> in 
generate_haplotype_concepts(temp_code_2, haplotypes)
     30 #                             + "\n" )
     31             index_gene += 1
---> 32         elif (genes[index_gene] == genes[index_gene-1]):
     33             print("+" + str(temp_code_2) + "|"
     34                   + gene_parent_medcodes[index_parent_code] + 
"|"

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Apologies for any typos I've made...I've tried posting simpler code than what I'm actually doing but the issue is the same...any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, you're doing `index_gene += 1` twice. Remove the `index_gene += 1` line inside the `if` statement.

Comment: dont try to do the grouping manually. Use `itertools.groupby` instead and build up a lists of values, which you can then use `str.join` to add the pipe characters e.g. for `+21|+0|CFTR F508del(CTT)` build up a list x = `['+21', '+0', 'CFTR F508del(CTT)']` then do `'|'.join(x)`, it will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thank you!  Now I have the first haplotype repeated twice, so I'm debugging that at the moment...

Comment: You didn't define a gene_parent_medcodes. You can't use [0] as part of a variable name. One of the "if-else" cases uses index_gene-1, all the rest use index_gene. Instead of (incorrectly) keeping a counter, use enumerate. Validate len(genes)==len(haplotypes) or throw exception.

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo and gene_parent_medcodes is declared as empty list somewhere above in original code.  Also the [0] in the variable name is just a tuple returned by a function not shown above, so I am accessing the first element in the tuple there, which is a list.  I'm not sure what's wrong with the "if-else" using a index_gene - 1, bc I do want it to assign the previous code in that instance.  The length of genes and haplotypes are the same and cannot be different under the test circumstances I have, but I realize that that's only apparent to me...The tip about enumerate is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
gene_concepts = {} # just initializes an empty dictionary to fill on the next line

gene_concepts[0] = ['+0|+77|CFTR', '+12|+77|CYP2C19']

# we don't actually end up using the genes list, since we can get the same info from the first part of each haplotype
genes = ['CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 
'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 
'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19'] 

haplotypes = ['CFTR F508del(CTT)', 'CFTR F508del(TCT)', 'CFTR G1244E', 
'CFTR G1349D', 'CFTR G178R', 'CFTR G551D', 'CFTR G551S', 'CFTR S1251N', 
'CFTR S1255P', 'CFTR S549N', 'CFTR S549R(A>C)', 'CFTR S549R(T>G)', 
'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10',
'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10']

# split the gene_concepts strings into usable pieces
gene_concept_codes = {} # create a dictionary for looking up gene_concepts by gene name
for gene_concept in gene_concepts[0]:
    pieces = gene_concept.split('|')  # this turns a string like "+0|+77|CFTR" into a list like ["+0", "+77", "CFTR"]
    gene_concept_codes[pieces[2]] = pieces # add the list to the dictionary, with the gene name as key

temp_id = 20 # arbitrary to match your values, change it however you need

# for each haplotype, match it up with the right gene_concept info
for haplotype in haplotypes:
    temp_id += 1
    gene = haplotype.split()[0] # pull out the name of the gene
    print("+{}|{}|{}".format(temp_id, gene_concept_codes[gene][0], haplotype)) # gene_concept_codes[gene] will be the list like ["+0", "+77", "CFTR"], so [0] gives us the first element of that list
```

That gives the desired output:

```
+21|+0|CFTR F508del(CTT)
+22|+0|CFTR F508del(TCT)
+23|+0|CFTR G1244E
+24|+0|CFTR G1349D
+25|+0|CFTR G178R
+26|+0|CFTR G551D
+27|+0|CFTR G551S
+28|+0|CFTR S1251N
+29|+0|CFTR S1255P
+30|+0|CFTR S549N
+31|+0|CFTR S549R(A>C)
+32|+0|CFTR S549R(T>G)
+33|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+34|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+35|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+36|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+37|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+38|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+39|+12|CYP2C19 *10
+40|+12|CYP2C19 *10
```

Comment: Wow, such neat solution! Can you explain what the point of gene_concept_codes = {} is? Bc if I delete it from the code and run exactly as is otherwise it gives the same output still.  Also this: gene_concept_codes[gene][0] in the very last print line of your code...what is it doing exactly? I'm confused about how that piece works...gene is whatever substring that was extracted from the haplotype...but the second brackets with [0] confuses me...what is this accessing?

Comment: @potato, I added more comments that should answer your questions. Cystic fibrosis is personally important, so please let me know if I can provide more clarification or assistance. I'll write your whole program if it'll bring us closer to understanding the CFTR gene. :)

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it! I'll definitely let you know if I run into more issues...if you're curious about the project, it's to see if we can get info about how gene variants impact drug dosing to clinicians... Patients with certain CFTR haplotypes seem to respond to different drugs better essentially.

Answer (score 2):

The following may be helpful (note the importance of checking for unexpected conditions):

```py
haplotypes    = ['CFTR F508del(CTT)', 'CFTR F508del(TCT)', 'CFTR G1244E', 'CFTR G1349D', 'CFTR G178R', 'CFTR G551D', 'CFTR G551S', 'CFTR S1251N', 'CFTR S1255P', 'CFTR S549N', 'CFTR S549R(A>C)', 'CFTR S549R(T>G)', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10']
gene_concepts = {'CFTR':0, 'CYP2C19':12} #Dictionaries are useful
for x in haplotypes:
  prefix       = x.split()[0] #Get prefix by splitting on spaces and looking at substring before first space
  if prefix in gene_concepts: #Do we recognize this gene concept?
    print("{0}|{1}".format(gene_concepts[prefix],x))
  else:                       #If not, inform the user
    print('Gene with unknown concept: "{0}"'.format(x))
```

Gives output:

```
0|CFTR F508del(CTT)
0|CFTR F508del(TCT)
0|CFTR G1244E
0|CFTR G1349D
0|CFTR G178R
0|CFTR G551D
0|CFTR G551S
0|CFTR S1251N
0|CFTR S1255P
0|CFTR S549N
0|CFTR S549R(A>C)
0|CFTR S549R(T>G)
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
12|CYP2C19 *10
```

Which may not be exactly what you are looking for but is, I think, closer. By changing the values in the dictionary you should be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have control over it, but your `gene_concepts` should be a dictionary. If you convert (as I do below), then the matching operation becomes a straightforward lookup:

```
gene_concepts = [None]
gene_concepts[0] = ['+0|+77|CFTR', '+12|+77|CYP2C19']

genes = ['CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR',
'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CFTR', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19',
'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19', 'CYP2C19']

haplotypes = ['CFTR F508del(CTT)', 'CFTR F508del(TCT)', 'CFTR G1244E',
'CFTR G1349D', 'CFTR G178R', 'CFTR G551D', 'CFTR G551S', 'CFTR S1251N',
'CFTR S1255P', 'CFTR S549N', 'CFTR S549R(A>C)', 'CFTR S549R(T>G)',
'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10',
'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10', 'CYP2C19 *10']

def generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts, genes, haplotypes):
    """Match gene id's in (genes+haplotypes) with genes in concepts list."""

    # Convert concepts into dictionary:
    gc = { t3[2]:t3[0] for t3 in map(lambda s: s.split('|'), gene_concepts)}

    # Look up gene/haplotype prefix in gc dictionary for concept
    for gene, hap in zip(genes, haplotypes):
        concept = gc.get(gene)

        if concept is None:
            hprefix = hap.split()[0]
            concept = gc.get(hprefix)

            if concept is None:
                raise ValueError("Missing gene/prefix: {}/{} in hap {}".format(
                    gene, hprefix, hap))

        yield concept, hap

print("##### Concept|Haplotype, no ID #####")
for concept, haplotype in generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts[0], genes, haplotypes):
    print("{}|{}".format(concept, haplotype))

print("\n\n##### ID|Concept|Haplotype #####")

for iden, (cept, hapl) in enumerate(generate_haplotype_concepts(gene_concepts[0], genes, haplotypes), start=21):
    print("+{}|{}|{}".format(iden, cept, hapl))
```

Comment: Great tip about converting to a dictionary! Will do

Answer (score 0):

To help you along with the main problem you seem to be facing in your loop, we should look at what you are looping over. Instead of looping over the genes, loop over your haplotypes instead, and then in each iteration take the part of interest and compare with the list of genes. The following example will help illustrate this.

```
for haplotype in haplotypes:
    if haplotype.split()[0] in genes:
        print(haplotype)
```

So, what is happening here, is for each `haplotype`, we are going to be dealing with a *string*. We see that based on the example data you provided, that we can *split* this string on spaces so we can only look at the first part of this split. What `split` does in Python, is actually take a string and convert it to a list based on some "separator". In this case a space. Then, the `[0]` part will simply take the first index of this list, which is the exact portion we are interested in.

From here, you will see we are using the `in` keyword. This will simply lookup against genes to see if the string of interest is in that `genes` list. Now you have your condition set for each haplotype you are interested in. From there, I believe you can just prefix that code as something like:

```
for haplotype in haplotypes:
    if haplotype.split()[0] in genes:
        print("your code {}".format(haplotype))
```